# FileSystemWatcher with other Methods Executing at the Same Time

Tags: c#

I am writing a program that has a FileSystemWatcher. I also have two other methods that I want to run alongside the FSW. But my other methods don't get executed because the program is always at the FSW.

Essentially, I want to have the FileSystemWatcher keep going and be able to perform other actions in my program at the same time.

How can I structure my code to achieve this?

Currently, my code has this structure:

```
namespace MyApp
{
 class Program
 {
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
     // call the FSW
     MyFileSystemWatcher(path);

     // call another method
     AnotherMethod1();  

     // call another method
     AnotherMethod2();
   }

   //----- file system watcher methods -----//

   private static void MyFileSystemWatcher(string path)
   {
     // code for the file system watcher
    FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    fileSystemWatcher.Path = path;
    fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
    fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += FileSystemWatcher_Renamed;
    fileSystemWatcher.Deleted += FileSystemWatcher_Deleted;
    fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true; 
   }

   private static void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
   {
        Console.WriteLine("File created: {0}", e.Name);
   }

   private static void FileSystemWatcher_Renamed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
   {
        Console.WriteLine("File renamed: {0}", e.Name);
   }

   private static void FileSystemWatcher_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
   {
        Console.WriteLine("File deleted: {0}", e.Name);
   }

   //----- end of file system watcher methods -----//

   //----- other methods in the program -----//

   public static void AnotherMethod1()
   {
    // code for Method1
   }

   private static void AnotherMethod2()
   {
    // code for Method2
   }

 }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when a directory, or file in a directory, changes. You are using it in the wrong way, see example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Please fill in the code of `MyFileSystemWatcher`, otherwise how would we know what is inside that is blocking the other calls?

Comment: @PeterBons, include the code for my FileSystemWatcher.

Comment: @urlreader, thank you for your comment. I have followed the same documentation from Microsoft and my FSW works quite well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your method async

```
private static async Task MyFileSystemWatcher(string path)
{
    // code for the file system watcher
}
```

then

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   // call the File System Watcher
   var task = MyFileSystemWatcher(path);

   // call another method
   AnotherMethod1();  

   // call another method
   AnotherMethod2();
 }
```

Alternatively, If you dont want to touch your method (not preferable), then

```
var task = Task.Run(() => MyFileSystemWatcher(path));
```

Comment: Thank you Simonare, I will try this.

Comment: Simonare, I tried the first method you recommended and it seems to be working, thank you!
I get this warning though "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread."

Comment: because your methods does not implements async behavior. for the proper implementation, you need to convert the implementation of MyFileSystemWatcher (body) to async as well. If you feel that this answer is helpfull, please consider to tick it as answer, so the community can benefit from it. regards

Comment: How can I convert the implementation of MyFileSystemWatcher body to async as well? If you can't edit this code accordingly, you could direct me to a link where I can seek some guidance.

Comment: there is nothing to be converted in your implementation. just use this `private static Task MyFileSystemWatcher(string path)` and `static Task Main(string[] args)` the latter is c# 7.0+ feature

Comment: I do want to mark your answer as accepted and will do after I have tested it few more times and it shows 100% success, thank you for your help I greatly appreciate that.

Comment: private static Task MyFileSystemWatcher(string path) does not work, Simonare.

Comment: Simonare, what if I have two such tasks, how can I make them run in the background and not hold the flow of the program?